# Words that repeat the initial letter

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

Suppose we have an alphabet of size $n$, and a particular set of words we may call "bad words".

We want to count the words of length $k$ satisfying two requirements:

1) they contain $p$ 'bad words';

2) they repeat no letter except the initial letter, which is required to reappear once and only once.

Notice that the second occurrence of the initial letter can be at any point within the word.

If we didn't have the second requirement, we could handle the first one, for instance, with the [Goulden-Jackson cluster method](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9806036v1.pdf).

If we didn't have the first requirement, the answer would be $n! \times (k-1) / (n-k+1)!$ (if I don't err).

The question is how you would handle both requirements simultaneously.

*Added Example*

Here is an example. Suppose we call 'bad words' all the following strings of two letters: (1,2),(2,3),…,(n−1,n),(n,1). Here I'm calling (i,j) the two-letter string composed by letter $i$ and letter $j$.

For $k = 9$ and $p=3$, a word of the type we are counting is $264591237$. The first requirement is indeed satisfied by this string because it contains $p=3$ bad words: $45$, $12$, and $23$. The second requirement is also satisfied, because the only letter that is repeated is $2$, which is the initial letter, as it should.

A string like $267314589$ is not of the type we are counting because the initial letter is never repeated; a string like $264591232$ is not of those we are counting, because the initial letter appears three times.

Comment: I don't understand the first requirement. Can you provide an example? For example, if we are talking about the English alphabet and "cat" is a bad word and $p=2$, what does it mean for a word to "contain $2$ occurences of 'cat'"?

Comment: As a basic example, suppose we call 'bad words' all the following strings of two letters: $ (1,2) , (2,3), \ldots , (n-1,n), (n,1)$. By $(i,j)$ I mean the two-letter string composed by letter $i$ and letter $j$.

Comment: And what does it mean to have "2 occurences"?

Comment: Now, the strings we want to count must contain exactly $p$ substrings of this type. In this case, Because the bad words have length $2$, of course $p$ cannot be larger than $k-1$.

Comment: But how can they have $p$ substrings of this type if they must not repeat any letter but the first one?

Comment: It means that if we call our string $(i_1, i_2, ..., i_k)$, then there is a numbers $s$ between $1$ and $k$ such that $i_s = i_1$.

Comment: Yes. But apart from that, you must not repeat any word. However, if $p=2$, then you must contain at least $2$ repetitions of some whole bad words, which is impossible if you are not allowed to repeat any letter.

Comment: As an example, consider the string 253412. It contains 34, which is a bad word, but it is also a string of the type we are counting, because only the first letter is repeated.

Comment: I understand that, but if $34$ is a bad word and $p=2$, can you please provide an example of a word that satisfies both conditions?

Comment: Take for instance 253412896. Here $p=2$ because there are both 34 and 89. However the only letter that is repeated is 2, which is the initial letter.

Comment: That is to say, the words we are counting must contain $p$ bad words, but of course these $p$ bad words will all be different from each other.

Comment: OK, I understand now. So $p$ must be smaller than the number of bad words.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm going to add an example into the question.

Comment: I'd think you could chop off the first letter and consider the remaining strings. Since all of them will contain at least one letter it will contain the strings with the necessary duplicated letter. The only hangup then is strings that begin with a bad word containing the first letter

Comment: Exactly, that's the hangup. I really have no idea how to treat it.